# Site for slice sheaf topos

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

The fundamental theorem of topos theory states that the slice categories $\mathcal{E}/A$ of a (Grothendieck) topos $\mathcal{E}$ are again (Grothendieck) toposes.

If $\mathcal{E}$ is of the form $\mathrm{Sh}(C, J)$ for some subcanonical site $(C,J)$, then if $A$ is some object of $\mathcal{E}$, can we write $\mathcal{E}/A$ as sheaves on $C/A$ (identifying $C$ with the representable sheaves) with an appropriate choice of topology on $C/A$?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, we can! For reference requests like this I'd always turn to the nLab. The statement you're looking for is [on theiry entry about over-toposes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/over-topos), in the version for presheaves. They reference page 194 of MacLane/Moerdijk for the version for sheaves.